# Windows 10 useraccount-SID exists without user - preventing sysprep

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, user-accounts

While trying to sysprep my OS to move to a new hardware structure I stumbled upon the error described in [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4057974) Microsoft support article. Trying to get rid of it I set up a Windows 10 Version 1703 VM and copied the MiracastView folder from there which didn't solve the issue.
On further investigation I found that there seems to be a user-SID which I cannot find connected to any actual account. Using `Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *mira*` produces the following output:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *mira*  


Name                   : Windows.MiracastView  
Publisher              : CN=Microsoft Windows, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US  
Architecture           : Neutral  
ResourceId             : neutral  
Version                : 6.3.0.0  
PackageFullName        : Windows.MiracastView_6.3.0.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy  
InstallLocation        : C:\Windows\MiracastView  
IsFramework            : False  
PackageFamilyName      : Windows.MiracastView_cw5n1h2txyewy  
PublisherId            : cw5n1h2txyewy  
PackageUserInformation : {S-1-5-21-1989392932-2341005969-1285330504-1000 [MyMainUseraccount]: Installed,  
                         S-1-5-21-1989392932-2341005969-1285330504-1010  
                         [S-1-5-21-1989392932-2341005969-1285330504-1010]: Installed(pending removal)}  
IsResourcePackage      : False  
IsBundle               : False  
IsDevelopmentMode      : False  
IsPartiallyStaged      : False  
SignatureKind          : System  
Status                 : Ok
```

However using `wmic useraccount get name,sid` shows this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>wmic useraccount get name, sid
Name                SID
Administrator       S-1-5-21-1989392932-2341005969-1285330504-500
DefaultAccount      S-1-5-21-1989392932-2341005969-1285330504-503
Gast                S-1-5-21-1989392932-2341005969-1285330504-501
HomeGroupUser$      S-1-5-21-1989392932-2341005969-1285330504-1005
MyMainUseraccount   S-1-5-21-1989392932-2341005969-1285330504-1000
WDAGUtilityAccount  S-1-5-21-1989392932-2341005969-1285330504-504
```

missing the entry ending on 1010 seen in the output of the other command.

I chose to take a look in the registry to see where that sid showed up and these are some of the first paths that were found:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\UserManager\Users\1044476
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Appx\AppxAllUserStore\DownlevelInstalled\S-1-5-21-1989392932-2341005969-1285330504-1010
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Appx\AppxAllUserStore\EndOfLife\S-1-5-21-1989392932-2341005969-1285330504-1010
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Providers\{D6886603-9D2F-4EB2-B667-1971041FA96B}\S-1-5-21-1989392932-2341005969-1285330504-1010
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\Creative\S-1-5-21-1989392932-2341005969-1285330504-1010
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\UserTile
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\NetCache\PurgeAtNextLogoff
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SystemProtectedUserData\S-1-5-21-1989392932-2341005969-1285330504-1010
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Search\Gather\Windows\SystemIndex\Sites\{S-1-5-21-1989392932-2341005969-1285330504-1010}
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows Search\Gather\Windows\SystemIndex\Sites\{S-1-5-21-1989392932-2341005969-1285330504-1010}
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade\Appx\AppxAllUserStore\EndOfLife\S-1-5-21-1989392932-2341005969-1285330504-1010
```

but the SID didn't show up under the keys `HKU` nor `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`.

By now I am completely lost where that key could come from, how I can remove it or whether it is safe to do so at all. Any hint in any direction would be highly appreciated!

Comment: After manually running the update to 1803 today, the SID doesn't show up in the registry anymore. However it still shows up for another problematic Appx-Package. If anyone knows the origin of that mysterious SID, I will gladly accept that as answer.

Comment: Another update: ... It's back. At least two packages are installed for that user and won't uninstall because of that. I cannot log in as that user because it doesn't really exist. A new user I created for testing has SID 1012 in the end. In the registry it shows up as essentially a new account with a good amount of Microsoft Software installed as Appx-Packages.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an [article](https://www.dxsdata.com/2017/11/manage-windows-10-modern-apps-via-sqlite-db-browser-solving-sysprep-issues/) that provides more detail to address the problem.  Here are the steps from the article here:

> Steps:
>
> 1. Open ProcessHacker as Admin
> 2. Select one of the vshost.exe processes -> Misc -> Run as this user
> 3. Choose DB Browser’s .exe file
> 4. Open file with DB Browser: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\StateRepository-Machine.srd
> 5. Open tab “Brows data”, then select table Package
> 6. Look for the apps to be removed, then delete the whole line(s) (button)
> 7. Finally, let DB Browser write the changes to the file

Comment: I already forgot that I had this question up here. And indeed, tempering with one of the systems databases at least partially helped. I never got a perfect sysprep through but I reached a point where I would just put my SSD on the new hardware and prayed (which worked). If you could post some more detail from that link, I will gladly accept your answer!